# Pivot longer into multiple columns with first two rows being separate columns

Tags: r, dplyr, tidyr

hopefully one of you can help me out in reshaping my data. I already searched for it, but was not able succeed.

My dataset`d` is the following:

```
structure(list(...1 = c(NA, NA, "y", "y", "y", "y", "y", "y", 
"y", "y", "y", "y", "y", "y", "y", "y", "y", "x", "x", "x", "x", 
"x", "x", "x", "x", "x", "x", "x", "x", "x", "x", "x"), ...2 = c(NA, 
NA, "101", "102", "103", "104", "105", "106", "107", "201", "202", 
"203", "204", "205", "206", "207", "208", "101", "102", "103", 
"104", "105", "106", "107", "201", "202", "203", "204", "205", 
"206", "207", "208"), ...17 = c("2000", "14", "0", "0", "0", 
"0.083333333333", "0", "0.083333333333", "0", "0", "0", "0", 
"0", "0", "0", "0", "0", "0", "0", "0", "0", "0", "0", "0", "0", 
"0", "0", "0", "0", "0", "0", "0"), ...18 = c("2000", "15", "0.333333333333", 
"0.416666666666", "0", "0", "0.916666666666", "0.083333333333", 
"0", "0", "0", "0.083333333333", "0", "0", "0.083333333333", 
"0", "0", "0.166666666666", "0", "0", "0", "0.333333333333", 
"0.333333333333", "0", "0", "0", "0.166666666666", "0", "0", 
"0.083333333333", "0", "0.166666666666"), ...19 = c("2000", "16", 
"0.5", "1.583333333333", "0.583333333333", "0.416666666666", 
"3.833333333333", "1.833333333333", "0.5", "1.25", "0.5", "0.916666666666", 
"0.416666666666", "0.166666666666", "0.75", "0", "1.25", "0.083333333333", 
"0.25", "0.333333333333", "0", "2.083333333333", "0.666666666666", 
"0.25", "0.666666666666", "0.333333333333", "0.666666666666", 
"0.166666666666", "1.5", "0.666666666666", "0", "1.416666666666"
), ...20 = c("2000", "17", "3.166666666666", "4.083333333333", 
"5.333333333333", "4", "13.833333333333", "6.333333333333", "3.416666666666", 
"1.666666666666", "0.583333333333", "6.333333333333", "3.083333333333", 
"1.416666666666", "4.75", "1.666666666666", "5.333333333333", 
"1.416666666666", "1.5", "1.333333333333", "1.666666666666", 
"4.583333333333", "1.166666666666", "1", "1.416666666666", "0.583333333333", 
"3.666666666666", "3.25", "2.916666666666", "2.5", "0.75", "2.666666666666"
), ...21 = c("2000", "18", "7.916666666666", "6.5", "6.666666666666", 
"6.666666666666", "17.5", "10.083333333333", "4.583333333333", 
"5.666666666666", "3.5", "20.5", "13.083333333333", "5.916666666666", 
"20.916666666666", "8.833333333333", "7.583333333333", "6.75", 
"3.666666666666", "6.416666666666", "5.75", "13.166666666666", 
"5.75", "2.916666666666", "5.083333333333", "1.333333333333", 
"20.5", "16.583333333333", "10.25", "16.833333333333", "10.333333333333", 
"10.083333333333"), ...22 = c("2000", "19", "11.5", "11.75", 
"8.166666666666", "7.666666666666", "25.083333333333", "10.5", 
"8.75", "10.083333333333", "6.833333333333", "40.166666666666", 
"38.666666666666", "15.25", "41.083333333333", "15.916666666666", 
"25.416666666666", "12.25", "10.916666666666", "12.416666666666", 
"12.666666666666", "25.333333333333", "11", "5.166666666666", 
"10.583333333333", "3.583333333333", "43.5", "38.75", "18", "39", 
"17.166666666666", "15.083333333333"), ...23 = c("2000", "20", 
"8.666666666666", "8.333333333333", "8.166666666666", "7.25", 
"19.583333333333", "11.583333333333", "6.083333333333", "9.75", 
"6.5", "39.166666666666", "35.833333333333", "17.583333333333", 
"41.583333333333", "14.583333333333", "19.416666666666", "15.416666666666", 
"13.083333333333", "10.916666666666", "16.25", "30.166666666666", 
"15.5", "7.5", "9.166666666666", "5.75", "53.833333333333", "50.416666666666", 
"23.083333333333", "49.25", "25.583333333333", "23.5"), ...119 = c("2001", 
"14", "0", "0", "0", "0", "0.083333333333", "0", "0", "0", "0", 
"0", "0", "0", "0", "0", "0", "0", "0", "0", "0", "0", "0", "0", 
"0", "0", "0", "0", "0", "0", "0", "0"), ...120 = c("2001", "15", 
"0.083333333333", "0.5", "0.25", "0", "1.083333333333", "0", 
"0", "0", "0.333333333333", "0.166666666666", "0", "0", "0.166666666666", 
"0", "0.083333333333", "0", "0", "0", "0", "0.416666666666", 
"0.416666666666", "0.25", "0.333333333333", "0.083333333333", 
"0.166666666666", "0", "0", "0", "0", "0.083333333333"), ...121 = c("2001", 
"16", "0.75", "1", "0.333333333333", "0.583333333333", "4.583333333333", 
"1.083333333333", "0.416666666666", "0.083333333333", "0.416666666666", 
"0.916666666666", "0.333333333333", "0.25", "0.333333333333", 
"0.416666666666", "0.833333333333", "0.333333333333", "0.083333333333", 
"0.416666666666", "0.083333333333", "1.5", "2.166666666666", 
"0.583333333333", "0.916666666666", "0.166666666666", "1.166666666666", 
"0.25", "0.333333333333", "1.333333333333", "0.75", "1.666666666666"
), ...122 = c("2001", "17", "3.25", "6.083333333333", "4.083333333333", 
"3.166666666666", "11.916666666666", "4", "2.5", "1.166666666666", 
"0.583333333333", "6.916666666666", "2.916666666666", "2.25", 
"4.666666666666", "2.416666666666", "5.5", "1.083333333333", 
"0.916666666666", "3", "0.916666666666", "3.75", "2", "1.833333333333", 
"1.166666666666", "0.916666666666", "4.5", "1.166666666666", 
"2.25", "4.833333333333", "1.583333333333", "2.75"), ...123 = c("2001", 
"18", "7.583333333333", "5.333333333333", "8.666666666666", "6.416666666666", 
"20", "7.666666666666", "3.416666666666", "5.916666666666", "2.083333333333", 
"24.833333333333", "16.583333333333", "5.75", "17.916666666666", 
"7.583333333333", "8.833333333333", "8.25", "5.833333333333", 
"9.25", "7.75", "16.916666666666", "6", "3.75", "5.416666666666", 
"3.25", "23.666666666666", "16.25", "10.666666666666", "21.583333333333", 
"9.5", "13.666666666666"), ...124 = c("2001", "19", "11.166666666666", 
"11.166666666666", "11.333333333333", "8.75", "26.166666666666", 
"12.75", "6.333333333333", "8.583333333333", "5.916666666666", 
"43.083333333333", "30.833333333333", "17.916666666666", "42.75", 
"17.166666666666", "19.583333333333", "12.416666666666", "12.083333333333", 
"11.75", "12.333333333333", "24", "11.083333333333", "7.333333333333", 
"10.833333333333", "3.5", "45.666666666666", "35.75", "17.916666666666", 
"40", "15.583333333333", "21.75"), ...125 = c("2001", "20", "12.083333333333", 
"5.833333333333", "9.25", "6.75", "20", "8.416666666666", "7.833333333333", 
"8", "8.166666666666", "46", "40.333333333333", "19.75", "49.333333333333", 
"15.166666666666", "19.25", "19.25", "16.5", "14.5", "14.916666666666", 
"31.416666666666", "13.416666666666", "6.5", "15.166666666666", 
"6.666666666666", "58.833333333333", "49.166666666666", "29.166666666666", 
"61.833333333333", "24.833333333333", "23.083333333333")), row.names = c(NA, 
-32L), class = c("tbl_df", "tbl", "data.frame"))
```

I am trying to reshape the dataset into long format. The structure I want to achieve is:

```
y/x code year length value
```

where `y/x` refers to the first column of `d` only including `y` or `x` values, `code` refers to the second column of `d` including e.g. `101` or `102`. So far so good, but now the tricky part starts. `year` consists of the values in the first row of `d`, i.e. of `2000` and `2001`, and `length` consists of the second row of `d`, i.e. values from `14` to `20`. Last but not least, the remaining rows and values shall be mapped into `value`.

Can anyone help me out with this problem? Of course, I tried to use `pivot_longer()` from the `tidyr` package, but I quickly bumped into errors...

I appreciate any help!

Comment: what was the error you got?

Comment: How did you read in your data?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The issue is that you first have to clean your dataset to apply `pivot_longer`, i.e. the first two rows contain the column names.

```r
# Move rows 1 and 2 to colum names
names(dat) <- c("y/x", "code", paste(t(dat[1, 3:ncol(dat)]), t(dat[2, 3:ncol(dat)])))

dat <- dat[-c(1:2), ]

dat |> 
  tidyr::pivot_longer(-c(1:2)) |> 
  tidyr::separate(name, into = c("year", "length"))
#> # A tibble: 420 × 5
#>    `y/x` code  year  length value         
#>    <chr> <chr> <chr> <chr>  <chr>         
#>  1 y     101   2000  14     0             
#>  2 y     101   2000  15     0.333333333333
#>  3 y     101   2000  16     0.5           
#>  4 y     101   2000  17     3.166666666666
#>  5 y     101   2000  18     7.916666666666
#>  6 y     101   2000  19     11.5          
#>  7 y     101   2000  20     8.666666666666
#>  8 y     101   2001  14     0             
#>  9 y     101   2001  15     0.083333333333
#> 10 y     101   2001  16     0.75          
#> # ℹ 410 more rows
```